# Wildcard in the middle of a -Match

Tags: powershell

I'm searching through SQL scripts (via PowerShell) to make sure they're not using table variables. Here's my simple check:

```
$Script = $Script.ToLower()

if ($Script -Match "declare @* table"){
    #do stuff
}
```

So if the script contains:

```
declare @mytable table(
blah blah
)
```

it would recognize that and do stuff.

I tried `@*` and a few other options for a wildcard in the middle, since I won't know the table name. Is there a different way that I can use a wildcard in the middle of the string I'm searching for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-like` instead of `-match` so the wildcards behave as you need them to.

```
$script = @"
declare @mytable table(
blah blah
)
"@

if ($script -like "declare @* table*"){
    $true
} else {
    $false
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that like statement doesn't trigger anything. `[string]$Script = " blah blah declare @mytable table blah blah"` and I tried both `if ($Script -like "declare @* table*"){` and `if ($Script -like "declare @* table"){`

Comment: The script you gave did not show anything coming before `declare` so I assumed that it was the beginning of the line. Simply add an * before declare to take care of that.

Comment: that was it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The `-match` operator evaluates things using [regular expressions (regex)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions). The `@*` in your matching string will match 0 or more `@` characters rather than `@` plus any characters following it.

The `-like` operator uses the more simplistic wildcard expressions you're used to. Try switching to that.

Here's the official docs on [matching operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#matching-operators) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In regex for -match you would say `.*` instead of `*`:

```
"declare @mytable table(" -match "declare @.* table"

True
```